# How to hide the new gesture pill / navigation bar on my pixel 4a running android 11?

Tags: android-11, gestures, google-pixel-4a

I m trying to hide the pill bar to get more screen real estate but I can't figure out how to do it.

[image: Pill Bar Screenshot]

The bar is highlighted in red.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to hide everything related to the navigation bar on the bottom of my screen to have some sort of full screen experience. The gesture navigation is already active. It is showing a bar at the bottom which I don't want.

Comment: AFAIK, for Pixel/AOSP-based, there's no setting to hide the navigation bar completely. One of the ways to hide the navigation gesture bar is to [enter the fullscreen/immersive mode](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive). Some custom ROMs may provide this feature built-in (Lineage OS provides this on Nexus 5). Otherwise, 3rd-party apps may help (ref: [Force an app to full-screen mode](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/109829/44325))

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.